# React js TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, mern

I am using **"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0"** and in my **Activate.js file** I keep getting error on Chrome as below

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

This is my code sample for my Activate.js and I was using a **functional component** with **react hooks** now how this code is working is that when an email is sent to you when you Register and the email activation link is clicked it will redirect you to a button that is clicked so as for the account to be **Activated** and this is where exactly I get the **"Cannot Read property 'params' of undefined"**
The Code below is exactly where am getting the Error.

```
useEffect(() => {
/*   get token from params like /active/token
then decode this token and get name*/
let token = match.params.token; //Error is occuring Here
let name = jwt.decode(token);

if (token) {
  setFormData({ ...formData, name, token });
}
```

The Full Code Sample for the Whole **Activate.js** file is as below

```
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import authSvg from '../assets/welcome.svg';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { authenticate, isAuth } from '../helpers/auth';
// import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link as RouterLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Activate = ({ match }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    token: '',
    show: true
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    /*   get token from params like /active/token
    then decode this token and get name*/
    let token = match.params.token; //Error is occuring Here
    let name = jwt.decode(token);

    if (token) {
      setFormData({ ...formData, name, token });
    }

    console.log(token, name);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  const { name, show, token } = formData;

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/activation`, {
        token
      })
      .then(res => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          show: false
        });
        toast.success(res.data.message);
      })
      .catch(err => {      
        toast.error(err.response.data.errors);
      });
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 flex justify-center'>
      {isAuth() ? <navigate to='/app/dashboard' /> : null}
      <ToastContainer />
      <div className='max-w-screen-xl m-0 sm:m-20 bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg flex justify-center flex-1'>
        <div className='lg:w-1/2 xl:w-5/12 p-6 sm:p-12'>
          <div className='mt-12 flex flex-col items-center'>
            <h1 className='text-2xl xl:text-3xl font-extrabold'>
              Welcome {name}
            </h1>

            <form
              className='w-full flex-1 mt-8 text-indigo-500'
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              <div className='mx-auto max-w-xs relative '>
                <button
                  type='submit'
                  className='mt-5 tracking-wide font-semibold bg-indigo-500 text-gray-100 w-full py-4 rounded-lg hover:bg-indigo-700 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out flex items-center justify-center focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none'
                >
                  <i className='fas fa-user-plus fa 1x w-6  -ml-2' />
                  <span className='ml-3'>Activate your Account</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className='my-12 border-b text-center'>
                <div className='leading-none px-2 inline-block text-sm text-gray-600 tracking-wide font-medium bg-white transform translate-y-1/2'>
                  Or sign up again
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                <a
                  className='w-full max-w-xs font-bold shadow-sm rounded-lg py-3
           bg-indigo-100 text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:outline-none hover:shadow focus:shadow-sm focus:shadow-outline mt-5'
                  href='/register'
                  target='_self'
                >
                  <i className='fas fa-sign-in-alt fa 1x w-6  -ml-2 text-indigo-500' />
                  <span className='ml-4'>Sign Up</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-1 bg-indigo-100 text-center hidden lg:flex'>
          <div
            className='m-12 xl:m-16 w-full bg-contain bg-center bg-no-repeat'
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${authSvg})` }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      ;
    </div>
  );
};

export default Activate;
```

Below is the code for how am routing my Activate.js file

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardLayout from 'src/components/DashboardLayout';
import MainLayout from 'src/components/MainLayout';
import Account from 'src/pages/Account';
import CustomerList from 'src/pages/CustomerList';
import AssistantList from 'src/pages/AssistantList';
import MarketList from 'src/pages/MarketList';
import Dashboard from 'src/pages/Dashboard';
import Login from 'src/pages/Login';
import NotFound from 'src/pages/NotFound';
import ProductList from 'src/pages/ProductList';
import Register from 'src/pages/Register';
import Settings from 'src/pages/Settings';
import Activate from 'src/pages/Activate';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element: <Account /> },
      { path: 'assistants', element: <AssistantList /> },
      { path: 'customers', element: <CustomerList /> },
      { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: 'markets', element: <MarketList /> },
      { path: 'products', element: <ProductList /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <Settings /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: 'register', element: <Register /> },
      { path: '404', element: <NotFound /> },
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      { path: '/users/activate/:token', element: <Activate /> }, //This the route am using to route for my activate.js file
    ]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

Just to add on I was following a tutorial for example where by this is an example of what he was using to route the props in his activate.js file and this is where i think is the problem in my code not being able to capture the props I might be facing though in his tutorial he was using a later version of react and not the "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0" that i am using in this case but here below is an example of his code.

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
        <Route path='/' exact render={props => <App {...props} />}/>
        <Route path='/register' exact render={props => <Register {...props} />}/>
        <Route path='/users/activate/:token' exact render={props => <Activate {...props} />}/>
    </BrowserRouter> 
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBQ1A.png) is The Error Displayed on Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook:

```
import { Link as RouterLink, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Activate = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    token: '',
    show: true
  });
  const {token} = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    let name = jwt.decode(token);

    if (token) {
      setFormData({ ...formData, name, token });
    }
    console.log(token, name);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  ...
```

Comment: Thank You very much for this assistance tI appreciate, the error gets cleared but for example I can see the details in the  Chrome console but now I get a blank page and not the button that I could use to activate the account some extra help on how to make the page be viewed and not get a blank Chrome page please would be of much help.

Comment: @AJPHIL Don't you get another error? Anyways, it could be caused token is declared again in the line just below useEffect `const { name, show, token } = formData;`. Change the line I told you with `const params = useParams()` and then for reading the token use params.token

Comment: Let me try illustrating with images from Imgur think it will be easier, now let us go back to the section of the first question right when you told me to use const {token} = useParams right now when I added that line I got an error link is https://imgur.com/a/G60eTGf from the error in this link I decided to remove token since it was saying its already called then I tried as the link in the image below https://imgur.com/a/zJVmJbI after this I proceeded with checking on the Chrome browser with link image https://imgur.com/a/DNV76gj also as you can see the page  is blank  and get error on console

Comment: The above comment has images with illustrations to describe the first solution you had given me to make it more clear, Thank You

Comment: Ahh ok, I think your problem is in the line where you write `Welcome {name}` into an `<h1>`, it seems that **name** is an object instead of a string. Try with `Welcome {name.username}` or just removing it to test if that is really the error

Comment: Thank You Very Much its starting to come together right now I am getting a "401 (Unauthorized)" as my error on the Chrome console and here is the link to the image to the Chrome console https://imgur.com/ujMKLgf

Comment: Could the problem be {isAuth() ? <navigate to='/app/dashboard' /> : null} on line 
 59 in the image above because I was trying to reference it to how redirect is being used like for example {isAuth() ? <Redirect to='/app/dashboard' /> : null} as a way of Authrorization I think this could be the problem here image to code for reference is https://imgur.com/MUioUhJ  I was trying to use **navigate** because **Redirect** is no longer supported in the latest react version am using could this be the problem.

Comment: Now I'm not sure, maybe it is related with isAuth() but I don't know what are you doing there. But I also think it could be related with the axios.post that you make in the line 40, because the error shows the same url

Comment: Thank You Very Much let me submit another question, Thank You for all the Help, I reciprocate.

Comment: just asking for some of your help to review this question of my Login.js form its quite similar to this problem but the fix i applied here didn't quite work out successfully in this other form, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67964706/14049823

Comment: @AJPHIL ok, when I have some time I'll check it